# Need help setting up curl php extension

Tags: php, apache, curl

I have been trying to set up curl with php 5 and apache 2.2 for at least a day now and I have been thrown in so many directions. None of these directions worked for me. I have uncommented the 
`extension=php_curl.dll`
and set the 
`extension_dir = "c:\php\ext"`

All of this was in the `c:\php\php.ini` I was then told that I am supposed to edit the `c:\apache\bin\php.ini`. I looked and there was nothing in that folder. If anyone could help me fix my problem I would appreciate it.

Edit: I have made a change in the httpd in my apache conf file to make it use the `C:\php\php.ini` file but it still does not load the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a `phpinfo()` in a PHP file and look which php.ini is being used exactly. The path differs from system to system.

Make the change there, and if the curl dll is present (it usually is)  you should be fine.

After restarting the server, look into `phpinfo()` again to see whether the module is present.

Comment: Configuration File (php.ini) Path:  C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File  :       (none)

Comment: @Mark then the windows one is the one to edit - if there is one